# tooltip position on resizable image

Tags: html, css, image, tooltip

First, I am not an expert in html/ccs coding.
I want to use the piece of code from (see below) http://codepen.io/ianfarb/pen/qkpJH
BUT in this example, the image and the position of the tooltips are fixed. In my case, I want that the image is resized when the browser width is resized. Moreover, the tooltip have to stay in the right position. Any suggestions?

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,400);

*  {  margin:0; padding:0;}

body     {  background:url(http://img.tapatalk.com/d/12/10/31/6yby7usy.jpg) center center;
            }

#container { background:url(https://lh3.ggpht.com/PQXITv6h0hTZLqlvlni7RSN2rE70QytYeNAtngBc3wKQuq8g5gH28EUDqYKgCPkWfQ=h900-rw) no-repeat;
      background-size:500px 293px;
      width:500px;
      height:293px;
      margin:25px auto;}

.tooltip   {  width:16px;
              height:16px;
              border-radius:10px;
              border:2px solid #fff;
              position:absolute;
              background:rgba(255,255,255,.5);}
  

.tooltip:hover
           {  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;}

.tooltip:hover .info {visibility:visible;}
  
 #first   {   margin: 200px 0 0 200px !important;}

#second   {   margin:75px 0 0 52px !important;}

#third   {   margin:158px 0 0 425px !important;}
              
.info     {   width:200px;
              padding:10px;
              background:rgba(255,255,255,1);
              border-radius:3px;
              position:absolute;
              visibility:hidden;
              margin:-105px 0 0 -100px;
              box-shadow:0 0 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);}

h3         {  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
              font-weight:100;
              font-size:20px;
              margin:0 0 5px 0;}

p           {  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
                font-weight:400;
  font-size:12px;}

.arrow {
  position:absolute;
  margin:10px 0 0 88px;
 width: 0; 
 height: 0; 
 border-left: 10px solid transparent;
 border-right: 10px solid transparent;
 border-top: 10px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="tooltip" id="first">
    <div class="info">
      <h3>Awesome Display</h3>
      <p>The world's highest-resolution 7" tablet puts over 2.3 million pixels in the palm of your hand. </p>
      <div class="arrow"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="tooltip" id="second">
    <div class="info">
      <h3>Stay Connected</h3>
      <p>Hangout and share your world with those that matter the most to you in glorious high definition. </p>
      <div class="arrow"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
   <div class="tooltip" id="third">
    <div class="info">
      <h3>Powerful Portability</h3>
      <p>Delivering the game and applications that help you have more fun and get more done. </p>
      <div class="arrow"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: if I change the code as suggested by Lajon, the tooltips are positioned in the proper right-left location when the windows is resized BUT the top-bottom location is not correct because the image height is reduced although the 'top' properties in the css is a constant in px. see code below any idea? thank you

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that you will need to change few things (see below):

Few changes to the background image to make it responsive:

```
#container {
    background: url(https://lh3.ggpht.com/PQXITv6h0hTZLqlvlni7RSN2rE70QytYeNAtngBc3wKQuq8g5gH28EUDqYKgCPkWfQ=h900-rw) no-repeat;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 25px auto;
    width: 600px;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Specify location for each spot:

```
#first   { 
    left: 5%;
    top: 95px;
 }

#second   { 
    left: 40%;
    top: 235px;
}

#third   {
    left: 90%;
    top: 135px;
}
```